# Java regex - split string with leading special characters

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to split a string that contains whitespaces and special characters. The string starts with special characters.
When I run the code, the first array element is an empty string.

```
String s = ",hm  ..To?day,.. is not T,uesday.";
String[] sArr = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
```

Expected result is `["hm", "To", "day", "is", "not", "T", "uesday"]`

Can someone explain how this is happening?

Actual result is `["", "hm", "To", "day", "is", "not", "T", "uesday"]`

Comment: There is a leading `,` in your input. The string is split on it the first time into `""` and the rest.

Comment: How can I update my regex to prevent the empty element being added? My goal is to add all words to array excluding any special characters and whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split is behaving as expected by splitting off a zero-length string at the start before the first comma.

To fix, first remove all splitting chars from the start:

```
String[] sArr = s.replaceAll("^([^a-zA-Z]*\\s*)*", "").split("[^a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
```

Note that I’ve altered the removal regex to trim any sequence of spaces and non-letters from the front.

You don’t need to remove from the tail because split discards empty trailing elements from the result.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted this answer because it shows me how to trim the beginning spaces/non-letters occurring 0 or more times.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify it by making it a two-step process rather than trying to achieve a pure regex `split()` operation:

```
s.replaceAll( '[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ' ).trim().split( ' ' )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still wondering why my regex didn't work and ended up adding the empty string. Can you explain?

Comment: Your regex is working fine. Because the first character of your string matches your regex, it is returning a the empty string as the first element. You can think of it like this: there is a 0-length string before the first `,` in your subject string.

Comment: @coffeefirst The first comma was matched by the regex provided to `split()` is the simplest explanation I can provide.